# Binding an action to a combination of mouse buttons

Tags: mouse, button, bind

I know that X-system limits binding an action to a combination of mouse buttons (e.g. right click + mouse wheel up/down which I used to bind to sound volume up/down in windows but I cannot do the same thing under linux) but I was wondering if there is any way to get around this limitation?

Thanks in advance for your response

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to map right click to Shift and have Shift + mouse wheel control your volume.

Or have something that listens for right click and mouse wheel and modifies your volume, but you'd still be clicking and scrolling while you did that. So your browser window would move while you adjusted volume. (A program can listen for right click pressed and then listen for scroll wheel. If right click released occurs, it stops listening for scroll wheel and resumes listening for right click pressed. I don't know if any such program exists.)

I don't think either of those do quite what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this xbindkey tool : https://github.com/mrtgenet/xbindkeys-guile-mouse-altkeys-and-more

You may find some information, notably binding many buttons using guile configuration. Here I use mouse side buttons + scroll to set volume up or down or set screen brightness